# How to get the initial state of a hierarchical xstate machine?

Tags: javascript, state-machine, xstate

Assuming we have the following simplified hierarchical [`xstate`](https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate#3rd-party-usage) machine...

```
const HFSM = Machine({
  initial: 'init',
  states: {
    init: {
      initial: 'leaf'
    }
  }
});
```

...what is the best way to get its initial state?

*Note that `HFSM.initial` returns me 'init' rather than `{init: 'leaf'}`*

Answer (score 1):

At `console.log(HFSM)` we can see properties of this statemachine, and also its methods, in **proto** property. The initial state is on HFSM.initialState, and if the value is what we are looking for, that is `HFSM.initialState.value`

Log into the console the following and observe the properties of returned object: 
`HFSM.getInitialState()` = the initial state of the machine, which is not started yet, and no transition attempts were made 
 - `changed: undefined` 
 - `value: {}` 
 - `event: {type: "xstate.init"}`

`HFSM.initialState`
 - `changed: undefined` 
 - `value: {init: "leaf"}` 
 - `event: {type: "xstate.init"}`

`HFSM.transition(HFSM.initialState, 'FAKE_EVENT')`= tries to transition from initial **state** (not state *name* - https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/transitions.html#machine-transition-method ), with a fake event so does nothing and remains in the state the machine tried to transition from 
 - `changed: false` 
 - `value: {init: "leaf"}` 
 - `event: {type: "FAKE_EVENT"}`

`HFSM.transition(HFSM.initialState, 'REAL_EVENT')` 
 - `changed: true` 
 - `value: {init: "leaf2"}` 
 - `event: {type: "REAL_EVENT"}`

Starting with xstate.js version 4.0 looks like we can use an interpreter, which can "keep track of the current state", among other useful things. https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/interpretation.html#interpreter.

So once this service is initialized: `const serv = interpret(HFSM)`
we can get initial state with: `serv.start()` or `serv.init()`.

`serv.start() === serve.init() // true`

Answer (score 0):

The way I approached this was to invoke a fake transition:

```
const currentState = HFSM.transition(HFSM.initial, "fake").value;
```